# Apache RewriteRule to rewrite subdirectories not working

Tags: linux, apache

I need to rewrite the following URL structure:

```
http://website.com/business-directory/25/administration/
```

to:

```
http://website.com/departments/administration/
```

I added this RewriteCond and RewriteRule but I cannot get this to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.com
RewriteRule ^business-directory/.*/(.*)/$ /departments/$1/
```

I have been testing with this online tool and I get successful results. But I don't know the logic they have behind the tool to validate rules.

```
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=11bb2f4c-7d70-5ee9-9551-2d81d5a5d340
```

I'm still new to Linux and Apache so my troubleshooting skills are limited. I have tried to search the error_log files and pipe all the rewrite entries with grep using this command, but there are no log entries. I am watching the logs in real time as I hit URLs that should be rewritten.

```
tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'
```

That comes directly from the Apache user manual.

The stack I am running is Bitnami Wordpress Multisite.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: jeprubio is right, verify mod_rewrite is enabled and RewriteEngine is set to "On". That testing tool is awesome, BTW. NFN but you know your RewriteCond is requiring a trailing forward slash? Without one, your rewrite will fail. Is that what you want?

Comment: i know the RewriteEngine is set to "On". i am verifying mod_rewrite now. i made the assumption it was enabled because the bitnami stack has RewriteRule entries as part of the default configuration. As for the RewriteCond, "i think" this is what i want, but maybe i am misreading the issue. prior to making this post i have commented that RewriteCond out and tested. the results were the same.

Comment: Sorry, the RewriteRule is requiring a trailing forward slash.

Comment: yes that trailing forward slash is needed. the way the urls are presented in the browser has a forward slash. i have tested it with and without and the results are still the same.

Comment: assuming i checked this right, i ran apachectl -M in terminal, mod_rewrite is enabled. i see rewrite_module listed under loaded modules.

Comment: Try creating a RewriteLog and set a high RewriteLogLevel. mod_rewrite can be very complex to diagnose. A RewriteLog will at least tell you if the RewriteEngine is ON. Also, I did not get the same results with and without the slash.

Comment: Also, are you running multiple hosts to the same site? Else, why the RewriteCond?

Comment: Yes I am running this site on a Wordpress Multisite installation, that is why I have the RewriteCond. I only need the rewrite rule applied to a specific domain.

Answer (score 0):

You've actually got a couple of problems. It looks like you want to convert `business-directory/NN/name/` to `departments/name/`. As I said, you're requiring a trailing forward slash after the department name. which is fine, but it will only rewrite the exact match to `business-directory/NN/name/` and will fail with `business-directory/NN/name/whosdead.html`. If you want to convert all URLs, you will need to capture whatever trails the department name:

`RewriteRule ^business-directory/.*?/(.*?)(/.+?)?$ /departments/$1$2`

Converts `http://website.com/business-directory/62/coroner` to `http://website.com/departments/coroner`

Converts `http://website.com/business-directory/62/coroner/` to `http://website.com/departments/coroner/`

Converts `http://website.com/business-directory/62/coroner/whosdead.html` to `http://website.com/departments/coroner/whosdead.html`.

Once you verify the rewrite engine is actually processing your rules, try this RewriteCond to see if it works better.

Comment: I'm testing this now. I think your rewrite of the rule will work more universally for what I need. The problem still exists but I don't think it is the rule. I think there is a Wordpress rewrite rule in place that's causing the problem. I am researching the logs now to see if I can figure out how to stop this from happening.

Comment: Be sure and post the solution, if you find one. I'm curious about the WP rewrite rule.